# Life expectancy of home appliances

Tags: probability, survival

I hope this is the right place where to formulate this question.  In a basic course in statistics we learn how to calculate the mean life time of an electronic device. Home appliances are electronic device of course, but all that we know when we buy one is the time length of warranty.

What is the relation of mean life time and warranty time in the home appliances? or better how is calculated the warranty time? What I am interested is how to calculate the probability that an appliance will brake within the warranty time.

Comment: Note that life expectancy and mean lifetime are the same only under certain conditions.

Comment: Different companies have different policies for offering a warranty. The mean lifetime is the average lifetime of a device and this usually does not coincide with the warranty. The warranty is typically chosen as a quantile in the left-tail of the distribution of failure times (*e.g.* $5\%$). This means that about 5% of the products will fail by that time. This value is chosen based on several criteria that consider marketing strategies and the aimed profit. For instance, expensive brands typically offer a long warranty (larger quantile, maybe $10%$ or more) for marketing purposes.

Comment: In addition, the definition of *warranty* varies among companies. Some of them offer replacement of the device by a new one. Some others ask you to bring the device to their repair labs and wait until their engineers fix it. This, of course, implies a cost that will be included in final price of the product. Moreover, the choice of this value is typically a trade secret. (BTW, intesting question +1)

Comment: @Procrastinator Good answer, if you put it in form of answer I will give +1 for sure.

Comment: @Procrastinator I made a little calculation. If we take a definition of warranty as the time where the 0.05 of the whole number of appliances selled will fail, and 1 year of warranty and an exponential decay for appliences, then this means that the mean life time will be more then 19 years. Is this true?

Comment: @Procrastinator I used a simple model (may be completly wrong). I used a exponential decay, considering time dependent variation of the numbers of well working appliances is a fraction of the whole
$$
\frac{\delta N(t)}{\delta t}=-\lambda N
$$
this means that if t is in years, after 1 years we still have 0.95 of devices working perfectly, namely
$$
e^{-\lambda t}=e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}=0.95
$$
I guess that with a weillbull or log normal, the mean life time will be bigger.

Comment: @emanuele It is important to notice that what you are modelling are the failure times, not the intervals between two failures. The $5\%$ quantile can be calculated using `qexp()` in R. For example, if the parameter $\lambda=0.25$ and the measures are given in years, then `qexp(0.05,0.25)=0.2` which is about 2.5 months. The mean lifetime is then $1/\lambda=4$. Now, if the $0.05$ quantile is $1$, then the parameter $\lambda$ must be $\lambda=-\log(0.95)\approx 0.05$ and the mean lifetime is $1/\lambda\approx 19.5$. So I guess you were right.